# PHP/Browser Performance: Generating thumbnails by the browser

Tags: php, javascript, performance, image-processing, web-worker

A user uploads a large resolution image to the server. A thumbnail needs to be created for this image. I thought about instead of having a GD intensive operation to create the thumbnail in PHP, can this process actually be off-loaded to the client/browser? Modern browers these days have support for scaling down images rapidly, but I'm sure there are many cons and pros of doing such a task, so my questions are...

1. This would be a more efficient way of doing it, but **how much more efficient** rather than GD operation on server side?
2. Is there any **Javascript libraries** out there that can **save an image in JPG** format quickly so it can be sent to the server via Ajax?
3. As a general note, the conversion will be done **using Web Workers**, so not to affect users browser.
4. Obviously the user can potetionally exploit and send a thumbnail that's completely unrelated to the full size image. Is there any good way around this, i.e. calculating quickly how alike the thumbnail and full size image is and if they are i.e. 98% alike, then allow the image?

I understand there are probably better ways of doing it, such as offloading to another server entirely, or doing a batch job at 3am for example, but for academic/informatic purposes, with the advent of modern browser and their improved Javascript engines, can work like this be put on clients browser?

Answer (score 2):

The similarity calculation will likely be no faster then simply creating a quick downscale, although I don't have code to prove this right offhand.

Bandwidth comes to mind as a possible issue, sending the file back and forth.

One possible idea is using a Flash/Java applet to handle the upload, automatically generating the thumbnail and sending it along.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought. I've looked into some image comparison algorithms and have to say, they look heavy. It would probabyl be quicker to just resize than do the calculation altogether. So I would have to just drop that calculation and hope the user isn't purposely sending garbage data.

Comment: The user could send a garbage image altogether, nevermind the thumbnail. If you're going to trust one, you may not have much choice but to trust the other.

Answer (score 1):

What I've been doing is grabbing the EXIF thumbnail on those images that have it and only creating real thumbnails for those that don't contain EXIF data.

Doesn't entirely answer your question, but it's my 2 cents :-)

Edit : I still queue all images for later full processing via a CRON job as they are resized to multiple sizes -> it's just getting that immediate thumbail that I'm concerned about initially.

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to be hammered with so many uploads per second that you have to distribute the load back out to the browsers?

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) can handle [resizing](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#resize) easily, and that could be threaded or offloaded to a separate machine if even that much is really necessary.

You should load test this before attempting to optimize something that is probably lost in the network transfer overhead anyway.

Comment: Although it handles it well, it's pretty slow with 300DPI images. 5 images take about 30-60 seconds to thumbnail which is no good when a viewer is waiting to see the result.

Comment: What version of image magick are you using? They've made some performance improvements lately. Also, GraphicsMagick was a lot faster than ImageMagick last time I checked, but is not as feature-rich.

Comment: 6.6.3-6 (from 2010). Haven't heard of GraphicsMagick. We do a lot of PDF and EPS to bitmap conversion so if it's faster it would be great as we don't need to work with a gazillion image types - just vectors and hi-res bitmap.

Comment: GraphicsMagick seriously rocks - it converted a 166MB tiff to a JPG in less than 2 seconds! Thanks for pointing me to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your messing up the client / server sides. Javascript can't generate a thumbnail. if you want to delegate the browser to scaling just set the width/height of the image

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your comments however I've found a good solution to this:

[**HTML5: Saving Canvas Image Data Using PHP And Ajax**](http://www.permadi.com/blog/2010/10/html5-saving-canvas-image-data-using-php-and-ajax/)

---

I'll do some further testing to work out it's feasability.

Obviously the main points/concern here are:

- **a.** I'm under no delusion that everyone is using the same browser, and with the same canvas/html5 capabilities, so a **fallback system should be in place.**
- **b.** Users have different performing browsers/machines. So this is something to keep in mind when working with large images to scale down to thumbnail size.
- **c.** Should any **garbage data/exploit** be sent from the browser/clients then I'll work around that when it comes to it (**the fact is, people could upload garbage data for the full size image**, anyway, and **if that users intention is to screw up the site in the first place, they'll always find a way**)

I'll do some testing to see performance improvements and report back here.